# Pointer and printing trouble

Tags: c

Define a struct (structure) containing three members, one float, one a string, and one a short array of floats. On the same line, printf the float, the string, and the first element of the array with spaces in between.
So I'm trying to print a float, a string, and an array of floats. I keep getting errors and I'm just brain dead at this point. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Structure {
float b;
char  c ;
float arr[4];
}; 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{
int x[4] = {3,5,6,7};
int i;
printf("This is the argument count -> %d\n",argc);
printf("This is argv[0] %s\n",argv[0]);
printf("This is argv[1] %s\n",argv[1]);
for( i = 0; i<=3; i= i + 1)
    {
    printf("%d ",x[i]);
}
printf("\n");
int  var = 20;   // actual variable declaration 
int  *ip;        // pointer variable declaration 

ip = &var;  

printf("Address of var variable: %p\n", &var  );

printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip );  

/*char izard[]="trump";
char *ch;
ch = &izard;
printf("Address of var variable: %p\n", &izard  );

printf("Value of *ip variable: %c\n", &izard[4] ); 
*/
struct Structure structure1;
structure1.b = 45.4;
strcpy( structure1.c, "Charizard");
strcpy( structure1.arr, "dog");
printf("integer : %c/n", structure1.c);
//printstructure( &structure1);

return 0;
}

/*void printstructure(struct Structure *name){
printf( "int : %d\n", name->a);
printf( "int : %f\n", name->b);
printf( "int : %c\n", name->c);


}*/
```

Comment: You're almost there. One mistake: the c member should be char array instead of char. There may be other errors, like copying a string to a float array, but the compiler is your friend and can help you locate them. 

Some gcc options I almost always use, are: gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu99 -Wwrite-strings. When I get in nitpick mode, I add -Wconversion just for the heck of it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should check these lines.

```
strcpy( structure1.c, "Charizard");
strcpy( structure1.arr, "dog")
```

`c` must be a char array. I don't understand why you copy from string to float.

```
struct Structure {
  float b;
  char  c[20] ;
  float arr[4];
};
```

Comment: the strcpy() function is only dedicated to null-terminated string. The use of `strcpy( structure1.arr, "dog")` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resolved. please see the below C code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Structure 
{
    float b;
    char  c ;
    float arr[4];
}; 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x[4] = {3,5,6,7};
    int i;
    printf("This is the argument count -> %d\n",argc);
    printf("This is argv[0] %s\n",argv[0]);
    printf("This is argv[1] %s\n",argv[1]);
    for( i = 0; i<=3; i= i + 1)
    {
        printf("%d ",x[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    int  var = 20;   // actual variable declaration 
    int  *ip;        // pointer variable declaration 

    ip = &var;  

    printf("Address of var variable: %p\n", &var  );

    printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip );  

    struct Structure structure1;
    structure1.b = 45.4;
    structure1.c = 'A';
    structure1.arr[0] = 4.4; /* rest of element required then initalize */
    // Error identified Reason: c member of struct which is character type
    /* strcpy( structure1.c, "Charizard"); */ 
    // Error identified Reason: Use character array instead of float type
    /* strcpy( structure1.arr, "dog"); */

    printf("integer : %c \n", structure1.c);

    return 0;
}
```